# jQuery: Save and Restore Selection State of a Multi-Select Box

Tags: jquery

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4gr0kdyj/

In jQuery 2.x I need to save and restore the selection state of a Multi-Select box. In between, I need to Select All options. The provided JSFiddle is too verbose and also it doesn't work, there's a bug somewhere. I'm just wondering, is there a simpler way?

Possible outcomes of the Save/Restore are

1. No selection
2. Some selection(s)

Strategy (too long)

```
// 1. backup state
var sels = $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"]').val();
// 2. temporarily select all
$('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', true);
// 3. restore state
if (sels != null) {
   $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').each(function(index, element) {
     if ($.inArray($(element).attr('value'), sels)) {
        $(element).prop('selected', true);
     } else {
        $(element).prop('selected', false);
     }
   });   
} else {
   // all deselected
   $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', false);    
}
```

```js
$('#deselectAll').click(function() {
  $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', false); 
});

$('#backupRestore').click(function() {

  // 1. backup state
    var sels = $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"]').val();
  alert('sels: ' + sels);
  
  // 2. temporarily select all
  $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', true);
  alert('selected all');
  
  // 3. restore state
  if (sels != null) {
    $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').each(function(index, element) {
        if ($.inArray($(element).attr('value'), sels)) {
        $(element).prop('selected', true);
      } else {
        $(element).prop('selected', false);
      }
    }); 
  
  } else {
    // all deselected
 $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', false);    
     alert('All deselected');
  }
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList" size="10" multiple="multiple">
<option value="103">Type1</option>
<option value="104">Type2</option>
<option value="105">Type3</option>
<option value="106">Type4</option>
<option value="107">Type5</option>
<option value="108">Type6</option>
</select>

<button id="backupRestore">
Backup/Restore
</button>
<button id="deselectAll">
Deselect All
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you are looking for this, but I got it to work.

I stored the backup in a variable and just use that to recover from. I also set your select to a variable name, that way it can be easily referenced later.

```js
search_Params = $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"]');

$('#deselectAll').click(function() {
  search_Params.find('option').prop('selected', false);
});

$('#backupRestore').click(function() {
  backup = [];

  search_Params.find('option:selected').each(function() {
    backup.push($(this).val());
  });

  search_Params.find('option').prop('selected', true);

  if (backup.length > 0) {
    search_Params.find('option').prop('selected', false);
    backup.forEach(function(_val) {
      search_Params.find("option[value=" + _val + "]").prop("selected", true)
    });

    console.log(backup)

  } else {
    search_Params.find('option').prop('selected', false);
    console.log('All deselected');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList" size="10" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="103">Type1</option>
  <option value="104">Type2</option>
  <option value="105">Type3</option>
  <option value="106">Type4</option>
  <option value="107">Type5</option>
  <option value="108">Type6</option>
</select>

<button id="backupRestore">
Backup/Restore
</button>
<button id="deselectAll">
Deselect All
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

[$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) returns the index so you need to check to see if its >=0

You can also shorten the code to below to reset the selected values

```
$('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', function() {
    return $.inArray(this.value, sels) >= 0;
});
```

```js
$('#deselectAll').click(function() {
  $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', false);
});

$('#backupRestore').click(function() {

  // 1. backup state
  var sels = $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"]').val();
  alert('sels: ' + sels);

  // 2. temporarily select all
  $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', true);
  alert('selected all');

  // 3. restore
  $('select[name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList"] option').prop('selected', function() {
    return $.inArray(this.value, sels) >= 0;
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="advocateSearchParams.answerMap[11].answerIdList" size="10" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="103">Type1</option>
  <option value="104">Type2</option>
  <option value="105">Type3</option>
  <option value="106">Type4</option>
  <option value="107">Type5</option>
  <option value="108">Type6</option>
</select>

<button id="backupRestore">
Backup/Restore
</button>
<button id="deselectAll">
Deselect All
</button>
```